# How do i add permissions to AndroidManifest via expo plugins?

Tags: android, react-native, http, expo, zebra-printers

My expo react native application comunicates with a zebra printer via a HTTP post request this works just fine in web , however on android and I suspect also iOS this isnt the case, from what i gather i need to add something along the lines of :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Into androidmanifest.xml however expo doesnt give you direct access to that file , so i need to make a [expo plugin](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/) that puts the permission into androidmanifest via expo.

I found this [post](https://chafikgharbi.com/expo-android-manifest/) teaching how to **remove** permissions however my current case requires me to **add** permissions ill still link the code from the post down here:

```
const { withAndroidManifest } = require("@expo/config-plugins")

module.exports = function androiManifestPlugin(config) {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, async config => {
    let androidManifest = config.modResults.manifest

    // add the tools to apply permission remove
    androidManifest.$ = {
      ...androidManifest.$,
      "xmlns:tools": "http://schemas.android.com/tools",
    }

    // add remove property to the audio record permission
    androidManifest["uses-permission"] = androidManifest["uses-permission"].map(
      perm => {
        if (perm.$["android:name"] === "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO") {
          perm.$["tools:node"] = "remove"
        }
        return perm
      }
    )

    return config
  })
}
```

Does anyone know how to add http permissions to my expo app? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To add permissions you do not need expo-plugins.

You simply need to add the permission in your app.json (or app.config.js if you have dynamic configuration)

> On Android, permissions are little bit simpler than iOS. In the managed workflow, permissions are controlled via the android.permissions property in your app.json file.

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/permissions/

Comment: for ejected, you need expo-plugins

Answer (score 0):

An example to add permission

```
/** @type {import("@expo/config-plugins").ConfigPlugin} */
const defineConfig = (config) => {
    const { AndroidConfig, withAndroidManifest } = require('@expo/config-plugins');
    config = withAndroidManifest(config, (config) => {
      let androidManifest = config.modResults.manifest;
      const permissions = androidManifest["uses-permission"] || [];
      androidManifest["uses-permission"] = [...permissions, {
        $: {
          'android:name': 'android.permission.WAKE_LOCK',
        }
      }]

      return config
    })

    return config
}

module.exports = defineConfig;
```